# Question about a Symbol in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

In the brackets of P, there is a symbol that looks  like a big U. What does that symbol mean?

Image taken from:
Hogg, Robert V., et al. Introduction to Mathematical Statistics. Pearson.

Comment: The union of numerable family of sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty $ is the union series operator, for a enumerated countble sequence of sets — in this case, events, which are sets of outcomes.   It is defined analogous to the additive series operator, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty $ but for union rather than addition, and sets rather than scalars.

$$\begin{align}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n ~&=~ C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3 \cup\cdots \\ \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n ~&=~ C_1\cap C_2\cap C_3\cap \cdots\\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n ~&=~ a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots\\ \prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n ~&=~ a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3\cdot\cdots \end{align}$$

The third property is that the probability for a union of countable many *disjoint* events, equals the sum of the probabilities for the events.

$$\mathsf P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n)~=~\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf P(C_n)$$